# Drupal is not defined - jQuery (Drupal 8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-8

I am sorry if my problem is stupid. My `jQuery` code works only when I am logged in as admin. When I am not logged, it is not working and I have an error in console: `Drupal is not defined`.

My `main.js` file looks this way:

```js
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
       code goes here
    });     
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

`mytheme.libraries.yml` (I created a custom theme) looks this way:

```
global-styling: 
  js:
    js/main.js: {}
  css:
    component:
      css/style.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - mytheme/slick

slick:
 css:
   theme:
     /libraries/slick/slick/slick.css: {}
 js:
   /libraries/slick/slick/slick.min.js: {}
 dependencies:
   - core/jquery
```

Please help.

**EDIT**

```
global-styling: 
  js:
    js/main.js: {}
  css:
    component:
      css/style.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - mytheme/slick
    - core/drupal
```

I added core/drupal to dependecies, no errors now, but jQuery still not works when I am not logged in.

Comment: Try add `core/drupal` to your dependencies

Comment: I edited my post now. Adding core/drupal didn't fully help :( @BrettGregson

Answer (score 3):

```
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not apply to you, but if you have the weight set, try removing it and make sure you have your dependencies listed instead.